# Query Update first string from the left

Tags: mysql

How Can I update strings which is containing 1 in my column.

```
#Select column from table
sample column: 100001, 100002, 100003, 100004, 100005, 100006, 100007, 100008

#How to update one at a time query?
update column: E00001, E00002, E00003, E00004, E00005, E00006, E00007, E00008
```

Comment: Want to change only the first one?

Comment: Is your column containing comma separated strings, or just one value per row? And what do you mean by "update strings which is containing 1 in my column"?

Comment: I mean like this 100001 to E00001, the reason why i need to update because there is 1000+ in my column containing 1 in the first character so i need to change it starting to character "E"

Comment: @user3736185 have you checked my posted answer? It work or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your values are not stored as comma separated the you can use [*`substring()`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to get the string after 1,and [*`left()`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function in where clause to check the value should have 1 as starting character

```
update t 
set `column` = CONCAT('E',SUBSTRING(`column`,2))
where left(`column` , 1) ='1'
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed409/1)

**Edit from comments**

```
update t 
set `column` = CONCAT(left(`column` , 1),'E',SUBSTRING(`column`,3))
where right(left(`column` , 2),1) ='1'
```

### [Demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a704d/1)

Comment: Last Question sir, what if I want to change the second character from the left not the first one, example: 110001 update to 1E0001

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE table
SET `column` = CONCAT(
                   REPLACE(
                      LEFT(`column`,1), '1', 'E'),      
                      SUBSTRING(`column`, 2));
```